# Partition with type boolean always get true in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Recently I installed CDH5.4.4 which have `Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.4` included, then I got something strange in Hive:

```
CREATE TABLE boolean_partition_test
(
`assert` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
`isreal` boolean
);

insert into table boolean_partition_test partition(isreal=false) 
select 'Cloudy' from dual where ds='2015-11-01' limit 1;
```

Can't I believe when I ran the following queries:

```
hive> show partitions boolean_partition_test;
OK
isreal=false
Time taken: 0.158 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select * from boolean_partition_test;
OK
Cloudy  true
Time taken: 0.27 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I even got the directory in HDFS: `/user/hive/warehouse/boolean_partition_test/isreal=false`

Then I tried the dynamic partition way:

```
CREATE TABLE boolean_partition_test2
(
`assert` string)
PARTITIONED BY (
`isreal` boolean
);

insert into table boolean_partition_test2 partition(isreal) 
select 'Cloudy' as assert, false as isreal from dual where ds='2015-11-01' limit 1;
```

Things still.. After I changed field `isreal` to type `string`, things got back to normal, however it's not what I want at the moment. So what turned Hive such a naughty kid in this case?

Answer (score 3):

`Hive` does not properly work with Boolean partition columns.

Please refer the below links

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6590

http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_boolean.html